# `load-path`, `exec-path`

Tags: load-path, exec-path

For some reason certain executables are not being found when I add them to the load patch but others are, while n the same directory. For example I got clang-format under `usr/local/bin` and I have

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(require 'clang-format)
```

This in my `init.el`. It works just fine.

Now I installed hindent for Haskell (https://github.com/commercialhaskell/hindent) and put the executable `hindent` also under `usr/local/bin`.

In the same fashion I put

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(require 'hindent)
```

in my `init.el`.

However when I load Emacs (GUI and shell) I will get "cannot open load file: No such file or directory, hindent".

Has this to do with emacs? I don't see why it would produce an error for the one file but not the other.

Comment: `exec-path` is where subprocesses find executable files. so your emacs should be able to find the executable. However, `require` is looking not for the executable, but for `hindent.el` (or the compiled file) which is the emacs lisp interface to `hindent`. You have to modify `load-path` for that (or put  `hindent.el` in one of the directories that is in the load path already).

Comment: @Nick: Please post that as an answer. OP: Please consider accepting it as the answer (unless you get another answer that you find more appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec-path` is where subprocesses find executable files. so your emacs should be able to find the executable. However, `require` is looking not for the executable, but for `hindent.el` (or the coresponding compiled file `hindent.elc`) which is the emacs lisp interface to `hindent`. You have to modify `load-path` for that (or put `hindent.el` in one of the directories that is in the load path already).